How can I create a custom tab bar that triggers onAppear
I need a custom tab bar for my application. The implementations of custom nav bar I've seen so far stacks screens in a ZStack and use opacity to conditionally show the selected screen. My issue is that a lot of my current logic relies on onAppear. And switching opacity doesn't trigger onAppear.
My question is if there are other ways to build a custom tab bar which keep track of state for each screen like the ZStack/opacity approach but also triggers onAppear. Or do I just have to adapt the rest of the app to not rely on onAppear?
In this sample code, you can see how switching tab triggers onAppear for NativeTabView but doesn't for my CustomTabView:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NativeTabView()
        CustomTabView()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

struct NativeTabView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Screen(name: "first")
                .tabItem { Text("first") }

            Screen(name: "second")
                .tabItem { Text("second") }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTabView: View {
    @State var currentTab = "first"
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            content
            tabBar
        }
    }

    var content: some View {
        ZStack {
            Screen(name: "first")
                .opacity(currentTab == "first" ? 1 : 0)

            Screen(name: "second")
                .opacity(currentTab == "second" ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

    var tabBar: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("first")
                .onTapGesture {
                    currentTab = "first"
                }
                .foregroundStyle(currentTab == "first" ? .blue : .black)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

            Text("second")
                .foregroundStyle(currentTab == "second" ? .blue : .black)
                .onTapGesture {
                    currentTab = "second"
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(height: 44)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}

struct Screen: View {
    let name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
            .onAppear {
                print("onAppear: \(name)")
            }
    }
}


I assume you also want each tab to retain its state? Otherwise you can just wrap each tab with an if currentTab == "first" { ... } instead of opacity.

Correct. Maintaining state is crucial.

It's unusual to need onAppear since in SwiftUI the UI is state driven, that is the data is already ready before creating the View structs that describe how to show it. onAppear would be too late.

You'd need to make your own onAppear and use that instead. Let's call this tabOnAppear. You can implement this as a PreferenceKey.
struct TabOnAppearKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: @MainActor () -> Void = {}
    
    static func reduce(value: inout @MainActor () -> Void, nextValue: () -> @MainActor () -> Void) {
        let curr = value
        let next = nextValue()
        value = {
            curr()
            next()
        }
    }
}

Note the ordering of curr() and next() affects the order in which tabOnAppear is called between sibling views.
Then the tabOnAppear modifier can be implemented as a transformPreference.
extension View {
    func tabOnAppear(_ action: @MainActor @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self
            .transformPreference(TabOnAppearKey.self) { value in
                let curr = value
                value = {
                    curr()
                    action()
                }
            }
    }
}

// usage:

struct Screen: View {
    let name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
            .tabOnAppear {
                print("onAppear: \(name)")
            }
    }
}

Note the ordering of curr() and next() affects the order in which tabOnAppear is called between parent and child views.
Finally, instead of wrapping the Screens in if statements, we put an invisible view wrapped in an if in the backgroundPreferenceValue. We can then use onAppear on that invisible view to call the preference value's closure.
Screen(name: "first")
    .opacity(currentTab == "first" ? 1 : 0)
    .backgroundPreferenceValue(TabOnAppearKey.self) { action in
        if currentTab == "first" {
            Color.clear
                .onAppear {
                    action()
                }
        }
    }
Screen(name: "second")
    .opacity(currentTab == "second" ? 1 : 0)
    .backgroundPreferenceValue(TabOnAppearKey.self) { action in
        if currentTab == "second" {
            Color.clear
                .onAppear {
                    action()
                }
        }
    }


To make this tab view more reusable, you can do
struct CustomTabView<Content: View, Selection: Hashable>: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedTab: Selection
    
    let content: Content
    
    init(selectedTab: Binding<Selection>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self._selectedTab = selectedTab
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ForEach(subviews: content) { view in
                view
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .opacity(view.containerValues.tag(for: Selection.self) == selectedTab ? 1 : 0)
                    .backgroundPreferenceValue(TabOnAppearKey.self) { action in
                        if view.containerValues.tag(for: Selection.self) == selectedTab {
                            Color.clear
                                .onAppear {
                                    action()
                                }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        // The bottom tab bar
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                ForEach(subviews: content) { view in
                    view.containerValues.customTabItem
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if let selection = view.containerValues.tag(for: Selection.self) {
                                selectedTab = selection
                            }
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(
                            view.containerValues.tag(for: Selection.self) == selectedTab ?
                                AnyShapeStyle(Color.accentColor) : AnyShapeStyle(.opacity(1))
                        )
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ContainerValues {
    @Entry var customTabItem: AnyView = AnyView(EmptyView())
}

extension View {
    func customTabItem<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
        self.containerValue(\.customTabItem, AnyView(content()))
    }
}

// Usage:

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = "first"
    var body: some View {
        CustomTabView(selectedTab: $selectedTab) {
            Screen(name: "first")
                .customTabItem {
                    Text("first")
                }
                .tag("first")
            Screen(name: "second")
                .customTabItem {
                    Text("second")
                }
                .tag("second")
        }
    }
}


For versions before iOS 18,

use ExtractMulti from View Extractor instead of ForEach(subviews:)
store the custom tab item as a view trait using _ViewTraitKey and _trait(_:_:) instead of ContainerValues
use id instead of tag to identify tab selections.

See my answer here for the specifics.

Interesting alternative but also seems to introduce complexity. What do you think about the other answer suggesting using the native TabView and hide the tabBar for each screen? @Sweeper

@WorldNeedsRefactoring Depends on how "custom" you want your tab bar to be, I guess. Using TabView closes some of the doors, like custom transitions between tabs.

@WorldNeedsRefactoring And to be completely honest, I had assumed that you already tried that approach before posting this question and found it to be inadequate for the customisations you want to do.

I'll need custom transitions going forward so I guess this is the way for me. Thanks!

The simplest solution might be to use a native TabView but with your custom tab bar:
// CustomTabView

var content: some View {
    TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
        Screen(name: "first")
            .tag("first")
            .toolbarVisibility(.hidden, for: .tabBar)

        Screen(name: "second")
            .tag("second")
            .toolbarVisibility(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
    }
}


Alternatively, you could try using a lazy container to hold the views. When the child views are no longer showing, the lazy container will usually drop them. I don't know if this is actually guaranteed, nor if it preserves state in the way you want it to, but it is worth trying.
For this approach, the state variable needs to be changed to an optional:
// CustomTabView

@State var currentTab: String? = "first"

Then the body uses a LazyHStack nested inside a ScrollView with scroll target positioning:
// CustomTabView

var content: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
            Screen(name: "first")
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                .id("first")
            Screen(name: "second")
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                .id("second")
        }
        .scrollTargetLayout()
    }
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
    .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    .scrollPosition(id: $currentTab)
}

